# How to bind Line end point (X2,Y2) to Point?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, line

Is there anyway to bind `Line.X2` and `Line.Y2` to `Point`'s `X` and `Y` ? For now, when i use

```
line.DataContext=testPoint;
line.SetBinding(Line.X2Property,new Binding("X"));
line.SetBinding(Line.Y2Property,new Binding("Y"));
```

it works for 1st time, then when i change `testPoint.X` or `testPoint.Y` it doesn't changes. What to do?

**[EDIT]**
I have many `Lines` and even it may increase, because of that i cannot create `Point` property for each `Line`.

Answer (score 1):

Bindings need to be updated for when the source changes.  You could make your Point a DependencyProperty, or make the class that contains the Point implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  Note that either way you will want to expose it as a property, not a field, because otherwise if you modify the X and Y values directly it still won't update.  When you expose it as a property, you can update a single value using a syntax such as:

```
TestPoint = new Point(newXvalue, TestPoint.Y);
```

This updates a single value but also triggers any setter functions such as PropertyChanged.

Here's a simple example for using INotifyPropertyChanged:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx

And a short example for creating your own DependencyProperty:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42203/How-to-Implement-a-DependencyProperty

Comment: The problem is that, that i don't want to set TestPoint to new Point. I want to use TestPoint like that: ... TestPoint.X=something . Every time when i want to change X, or Y, there is no way ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by `Moozhe`:

impelement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and write a wrapper property for your point:

```
public double X {
    get { return TestPoint.X; }
    set { TestPoint.X = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("X");
        }
}
```

same for `Y`...

and the event:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(String property)
{
    if (PropertyChanged == null) return;
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}
```

Comment: you couldn't understand me. I also mentioned that, if i had a chance, i would be inherit from it, and do things, you said above. Problem is that i have these "X and Y" combos more than one i class. Because that i couldn't implement this solution

Comment: "I have several "X and Y" in class and how to implement your solution?  For each Line i need to add property to my class ?

Comment: I don't understand...please update your question and show more code.

Comment: Why you need code? I said , but if you want , i will say again. For example, i have 100 lines, and you suggest me to create **property** for each. Even it may increase. What to do know ?

Comment: You want to bind one X and one Y (you can't bind 100), so what's the problem? I don't see why you have to create one property for each line.

Comment: Each line has own "X and Y" . If i need one, i wouldn't give question at here. Problem is that, i want to apply this, for infinite number of lines. Understand ?

Answer (score 0):

For WPF binding to work your testPoint must be an object capable of notifying property changes. If testPoint doesen't implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface then the behaviour you are seeing is expected. The line endpoint is bound to the original value and changes are not propagated.
To solve your first problem make sure testPoint correctly implements the required interface.

For WPF binding to work on a collection of objects you must use a collection capable of notifying collection changes. If the collection of testPoints doesn't implement INotifyCollectionChanged interface then your lines endpoints will be bound to the the original number of objects.
To solve your second problem use ObservableCollection.

I'd also suggest using XAML to setup bindings instead of code behind.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a wrapper class for point which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface

   ```
   public class BindingPoint : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private Point point;

       public BindingPoint(double x, double y)
       {
           point = new Point(x, y);
       }

       public double X
       {
           get { return point.X; }
           set
           {
               point.X = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
               OnPropertyChanged("Point");
           }
       }

       public double Y
       {
           get { return point.Y; }
           set
           {
               point.Y = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
               OnPropertyChanged("Point");
           }
       }

       public Point Point
       {
           get { return point; }
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
       protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           var handler = PropertyChanged;
           if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Bind startpoint / endPoint X and Y properties to line

   ```
   Line line = new Line();
   BindingPoint startPoint = new BindingPoint(0,0);
   BindingPoint endPoint = new BindingPoint(0,0);

   var b = new Binding("X")
   {
       Source = startPoint,
       Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
   };
   line.SetBinding(Line.X1Property, b);

   b = new Binding("Y")
   {
       Source = startPoint,
       Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
   };
   line.SetBinding(Line.Y1Property, b);

   b = new Binding("X")
   {
       Source = endPoint,
       Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
   };
   line.SetBinding(Line.X2Property, b);

   b = new Binding("Y")
   {
       Source = endPoint,
       Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
   };
   line.SetBinding(Line.Y2Property, b);
   ```